# I calculated to get the first day of the month but go the last

Tags: javascript, typescript

I start by getting the date of the beginning of month:

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
```

Then I convert it to ISO:

```
firstDay = firstDay.toISOString();
```

Why did I get `2019-05-31` as the first day instead of `2019-06-01`?

Comment: You're converting the Date object to an ISO string, so you'll need to show the contents of `parseIDateFromString`

Comment: Could you post the `Helper.parseIDateFromString` function? The problem is probably related to timezone...

Comment: Sorry, I updated question,

Comment: It's because of your timezone.

Comment: How to avoid timezone and get beginning of month?

Comment: I have personally ran into some silent inaccuracies in JavaScript dates (due to my ignorance i guess). What are your views on dependencies in your project? Would you be against using moment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regex to format the string using replace:

```
/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).+/
```

```js
// Set the inital date to a UTC date
var date = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "UTC"}))

// Update the day without affecting the month/day when using toISOString()
date.setDate(1)

// Format the date
let formatted = date.toISOString().replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}).+/, '$3-$2-$1')

console.log(formatted)
```

Comment: Is it considering timezone?

Comment: It is still using `toISOString()`, is that what you want?

Comment: I need to get beginning of month without timezone in ISO format

Comment: It is getting the beginning of the month using the users current time then converts it to UTC and formats it. Basically it is converted to UTC before it is formatted.

Comment: I need bginnig of current month it is 01-06-2019 not 31-05-2019

Comment: My output displays `01-06-2019`

Comment: In my PC it is another time, so it is problem for me

Comment: What time and timezone do you have so I can test?

Comment: I have 5 June 10:22 PM

Comment: UTC +04:00 this timezone

Comment: How to get last date?

Comment: Set up date.setDate(31) or date.setDate(30)?

Comment: I did another update, as I was finding issues in other timezones. This seems to work with all timezones now.

Answer (score 1):

The default javascript date uses your local timezone, by converting it to something else you can end up with a different date.

Comment: ISO Time also uses `UTC`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it

```js
var firstDay = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 8) + '01';

console.log(firstDay);
```

Comment: `new Date().toISOString()` returns the ISO format of the date in your timezone like `2019-06-05T18:00:00.818Z`. `.slice()` cuts this string to `2019-06-` and I added `01` at the end of it. So it should work with any timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The date object in javascript can be somewhat tricky. When you create a date, it is created in your local timezone, but toISOString() gets the date according to UTC. The following should convert the date to ISO but keep it in your own time zone.

```js
var date = new Date();

var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);

var day = 0;
if (firstDay.getDate() < 10) {
  day = '0' + firstDay.getDate();
}

var month = 0;
if ((firstDay.getMonth() + 1) < 10) {
  //months are zero indexed, so we have to add 1
  month = '0' + (firstDay.getMonth() + 1);
}

firstDay = firstDay.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;

console.log(firstDay);
```